# Bundle Ghostscript using Pyinstaller to python tool?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller, ghostscript

I am using Windows-10, Python 3.7, Pillow version 6.0.0, tkinter.

I developed a GUI tool which saves tkinter canvas as a PostScript using tkitner library, then converts it to PNG file using PIL (Pillow) library. On my Computer, I already have Ghostscript installed and my tool works just fine.

After distributing my tool with my collages, they can save the canvas as PostScript fine, but the tool then can't convert to PNG file and a anError arise regarding Ghostscript.

> OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths

I would like to enable my Colleges of running the tool without the need of downloading Ghostscript on there machines.

I though then of including (bundling) the Ghostscript when creating py_app.exe using Pyinstaller.

Does anyone know how to do this, or have any other suggestions.

Below is the error message:

```
  Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "user_input.py", line 49, in save_as
  File "drawing_func.py", line 1232, in save_as_png
  File "site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1973, in save
  File "site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 628, in _ensure_mutable
  File "site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 621, in _copy
  File "site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 333, in load
  File "site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 139, in Ghostscript
  OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths
```

Comment: I suggest reading the licencing of Adobe first. Are you allowed to bundle it?

Comment: Ghostscript isn't Adobe. Ghostscript is supplied by Artifex, and it is supplied under the AGPL v3. If you expect to use Ghostscript without linking against it, then you will almost certainly need to run the Ghostscript installer (or do a lot of work yourself). The obvious answer is to include the Ghostscript installer, which will also pretty much absolve you from any further obligations under the AGPL since the attribution is clear in that case. I'm pretty certain Artifex won't be happy about you installing Ghostscript yourself without significant attribution in your installer.

Comment: Do you mean by including Ghostscript installer to just include the normal installer file for it, then the collages should manually download it on there PCs? @KenS

Comment: If you include the Ghostscritp installer in your package, then your 'collages' (colleges ? Colleagues ?) won't have to download it. Given the Ghostscript installer does more than simply copy files to a disk you would have to duplicate the action of the installer, its surely easier just to supply the installer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. (Colleagues!)

Comment: can anyone suggest how to add Ghostscript installer to package?